# How to use _formwizard.scss in ABP template?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, aspnetboilerplate, formwizard

ASP.NET Boilerplate (ABP) template contains a file named **_formwizard.scss**, containing CSS styles like:

```css
.wizard,
.tabcontrol {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wizard a,
.tabcontrol a {
    outline: 0;
}

/* ... */
```

Where does this file come from and how do I use it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from [AdminBSB](https://github.com/gurayyarar/AdminBSBMaterialDesign), using the [jQuery Steps](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps) plugin.

You can use it as shown in their demo:
https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/forms/form-wizard.html

```html
<div id="wizard_horizontal">
  <h2>First Step</h2>
  <section>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum...
    </p>
  </section>

  <h2>Second Step</h2>
  <section>
    <p>
      Donec mi sapien...
    </p>
  </section>
</div>
```

```js
$('#wizard_horizontal').steps({
    headerTag: 'h2',
    bodyTag: 'section',
    transitionEffect: 'slideLeft',
    onInit: function (event, currentIndex) {
        setButtonWavesEffect(event);
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
        setButtonWavesEffect(event);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @aaron for these additional infos. Greatly appreciated.